# Excel VBA - Search for a specific character, select any non-empty cells without that character, perform a second subroutine on the selected cells

Tags: vba, excel

I'm a newbie to Excel VBA (only one formal course so far), and I've been trying to cobble together a VBA macro using bits and pieces gleaned from this and other Excel sites, but after several days I feel that I've reached an impasse.

What I'm trying to do:

- Search Columns C, D, E, G, H, I, K, L for the character "°",
  beginning with Row 6, ending with Row 200 for each of the above columns.
- If "°" appears in any cell in the above ranges, then no action is taken on that cell.
- If the cell is completely empty, then no action is taken on that cell.
- If "°" does NOT appear in any cell in the above ranges, and the cell is NOT completely empty, then the cell is selected or activated, and a second subroutine is called.
- The second subroutine places the "°" character in the 5th position from the end of the cell (equivalent to hitting F2, moving left 5 positions, and inserting "°").

The latest version of what I've written:

```
Sub CheckTestColC()
     Dim a As String
     Dim cell As C6: C200
     For Each cell In Selection
       If InStr(1, cell, "°", 1) Then
       Cells(ActiveCell.Row + 1, ActiveCell.Column).Select
       Else
       ActiveCell.Value = a
       Call AddDegree
       End If
     Next
     End Sub

Sub AddDegree()

    SendKeys "{F2}"
    Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
    SendKeys "{LEFT 5}"
    Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
    SendKeys "°"
    Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
    SendKeys "{ENTER}"

 End Sub
```

Again, I am a complete novice to this, so I apologize in advance if my coding seems ridiculous to you experienced folks. ;-)

I'm happy to see corrections to the above coding, or if there are "better/stronger/faster" ways to solve this using a completely different path, then please steer me in the right direction.  I very much want to learn! :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you say you are so new to VBA here's an example of you code that demonstrates a few concepts worth learning.

1. Abstract your logic from your inputs.  That way you can reuses the code more easily
2. Restrict the size of loops over ranges (they are *slow*).  `SpecialCells` helps to reduce the range to potential cells of interest.  Even better, use a Variant Array (look it up on SO)
3. Don't use SendKeys.  Ever.  (well, unless you have a really, really good reason)
4. Handle potential input anomalies

---

```
Sub Demo()
    ' Process Rows 6:200 of columns C, D, E, G, H, I, K, L on active sheet
    FindDeg Range("C6:E200"), "°", 5, False
    FindDeg Range("G6:I200"), "°", 5, False
    FindDeg Range("K6:L200"), "°", 5, False
End Sub

Private Sub FindDeg(rng As Range, InsertString As String, AtPosition As Long, Optional FromLeft As Boolean = True)
    Dim rngTextCells As Range, cl As Range
    Dim str As String

    ' Select non-blank cells containing text
    ' (ie ignore formulas, numbers and errors)
    On Error Resume Next
    Set rngTextCells = rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues)
    Err.Clear
    On Error GoTo 0

    ' If any found
    If Not rngTextCells Is Nothing Then
        '  Loop through cells
        For Each cl In rngTextCells
            If Not cl.Value Like "*" & InsertString & "*" Then
                ' Cell does not contain °
                str = CStr(cl.Value)
                If Len(str) < AtPosition Then
                    ' what if it's too short?
                    MsgBox "cell = " & str & vbNewLine & "What now?"
                    Exit Function
                End If

                ' Insert string at position (no need to that SensKeys nonsense
                If FromLeft Then
                    cl = Left$(str, AtPosition) & InsertString & Mid$(str, AtPosition + 1)
                Else
                    cl = Left$(str, Len(str) - AtPosition) & InsertString & Right$(str, AtPosition)
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you all for taking the time to help.  Sorry for the belated “thank you,” but I ended up having some family issues and then an emergency surgery (minor, thankfully), so I’ve been away for a bit. Please accept my apologies.  Each of your responses was helpful in getting me to think about the problem and solution in a different way.  Again, many thanks to each of you! :)

Answer (score 0):

The example below requires some tuning, but it is close to what you need.

I used simple techniques that you should be able to understand, perhaps with some googleing. Look for help with Excel VBA, not with Excel. VBA doesn't talk to Excel via the keyboard (i.e. forget `SendKeys`), and doesn't need to select cells to modify them (i.e. forget `Select`).

For VBA every cell, worksheet, workbook, range, font, chart, etc. are objects. You can "read" or "write" them using their method and properties.

```
Sub CheckTestColC()
  Dim R As Integer, C As Integer, CLetter As String
  For C = 1 To 10
    CLetter = Chr(C + 64)
    If InStr("CDEGHIKL", CLetter) = 0 Then GoTo SkipColumn
    For R = 6 To 200
      If IsEmpty(Cells(R, C)) Then GoTo SkipRow
      If InStr(Cells(R, C).Value, "°") Then GoTo SkipRow
      Cells(R, C).Value = ModifyValue(Cells(R, C).Value)
SkipRow:
    Next R
SkipColumn:
  Next C
End Sub

Function ModifyValue(Txt As String)
  ModifyValue = Left(Txt, 4) & "°" & Mid(Txt, 5)
End Function
```

Comment: thanks for your helpful comments re: "Sendkeys" and "select".  I just tried the proposed solution, however the ° character didn't appear where I intended it to; I suspect this is because of the "Left(Txt, 4)" concatenation shown above.  I should have mentioned that the number of characters to the left of the desired position for the ° character is variable, while the number of characters to the right of the desired position is static.  Here's some sample data to illustrate:
5 BTDC
15 BTDC
20 BTDC
30 BTDC
8 ATDC  Can I drop that portion of the concatenation, or modify it in some way?  Thanks!

Comment: You can change the `ModifyValue` and all the rest as you please. Other answer are better than this because they use an array instead of scanning through the `Cells`. Here I tried not to give you the best answer nor a final working solution. I was trying to put you in the right direction with a (almost) working example that only uses basic concepts. Test it, modify it, experiment with it, get familiar with it, and when it's clear in your mind what's going on, you will understand also the other answers.

Comment: Thank you all for taking the time to help.  Sorry for the belated “thank you,” but I ended up having some family issues and then an emergency surgery (minor, thankfully), so I’ve been away for a bit. Please accept my apologies.  Each of your responses was helpful in getting me to think about the problem and solution in a different way.  Again, many thanks to each of you! :)

Answer (score 0):

I would not use SendKeys as it requires the user to not use the machine at all until it completes, and any other interruptions like popups will also break it.  I would use Left() and Right() instead.  Activating the cell is not required with this method,either.

You don't appear to be checking the cell has content as you explain.

The variable "a" has no assigned value, so you are in effect blanking the cells using it.

"Cells(ActiveCell.Row + 1, ActiveCell.Column).Select" Will not select the cell "cells" refers to, it will just keep selecting the next cell down.

Here is a rough re-write, I don't have Excel on this machine, but this is closer to your explained logic (without the need for a 2nd sub).  This version requires the cell content to be at least 5 chars to meet your 5-from-end criteria

```
Sub CheckTestColC()
     Dim cell As C6: C200
     For Each cell In Selection
       If InStr(cell, "°")<1 And Len(cell)>=5 Then
         'cell.Select  'Not required
         cell=Left(cell,len(cell)-5) & "°" & Right(cell,5)
       End If
     Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you all for taking the time to help.  Sorry for the belated “thank you,” but I ended up having some family issues and then an emergency surgery (minor, thankfully), so I’ve been away for a bit. Please accept my apologies.  Each of your responses was helpful in getting me to think about the problem and solution in a different way.  Again, many thanks to each of you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow and well done on your question and learning to-date!

In terms of "stronger/better/faster"

- Avoid looping through cell ranges, use a variant array for the manipulations instead
- Steer clear of `Sendkeys,` it's kludgy
- Before adding to a string in the 5th position, test that it is at least 4 characters first
- Use string functions `Left$` rather than the slower variants `Left`

This code works on your entire range, skipping columns `F` and `J`

```
Sub Uppdate() 
Dim X 
Dim rng1 As Range 
Dim lngCol As Long 
Dim lngRow As Long 
 'set initial range
Set rng1 = Range("C6:L200") 
 'put range in variant
X = rng1.Value2 
For lngCol = 1 To UBound(X, 2) 
    For lngRow = 1 To UBound(X, 1) 
         'skip every fourth column (F and J)
        If lngCol Mod 4 <> 0 Then 
             'skip values containing "°"
            If InStr(X(lngRow, lngCol), "°") = 0 Then 
                 'replace is string is 4 or more characters
                If Len(X(lngRow, lngCol)) > 3 Then 
                    X(lngRow, lngCol) = Left$(X(lngRow, lngCol), 4) & "°" & Right$(X(lngRow, lngCol), Len(X(lngRow, lngCol)) - 4) 
                End If 
            End If 
        End If 
    Next lngRow 
Next lngCol 
 'dump back to range
rng1 = X 
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you all for taking the time to help.  Sorry for the belated “thank you,” but I ended up having some family issues and then an emergency surgery (minor, thankfully), so I’ve been away for a bit. Please accept my apologies.  Each of your responses was helpful in getting me to think about the problem and solution in a different way.  Again, many thanks to each of you! :)